# Is there a setting in Prettier for formatting more concisely like this in React/JSX?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

When I use Prettier to format this code:

```
export default function CategoryItem({ name, imageUrl, idx, active, handlePress }) {
...
```

Because it is more than 80 characters wide, it formats it into this:

```
export default function CategoryItem({
  name,
  imageUrl,
  idx,
  active,
  handlePress,
}) {
```

But what I want to format it into something with less lines but doesn't exceed the 80 character limit:

```
export default function CategoryItem({
  name, imageUrl, idx, active, handlePress,
}) {
```

I couldn't find such a setting in Prettier in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: look here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#:~:text=For%20readability%20we%20recommend%20against,set%20to%20100%20or%20120.

Comment: already checked i couldnt find it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. The purpose of Prettier is to facilitate collaboration between teams in projects by enforcing consistent coding styles, not to be customizable to do what a user wants. What if another user who collaborates on your code wanted a different formatting style, and another user wanted something else, and another wanted something different? It's intentional for Prettier to format in such way to have a standard over coding styles, and for collaborators to follow those standards.

Comment: I can accept that Prettier can't do that but I don't think customizability is the issue. If they didn't want you to customize it, they wouldn't give you settings like semicolons or trailing commas to toggle in the first place. As for the example you gave about what if different users want different formatting options, that's what config files are for.

Answer (score 0):

In Vscode, go to settings and search for "prettier print". You should get something like this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That doesn't help me achieve the third code block in my post where the parameters are in their own line

Comment: I guess it can't be done.